# Как из словаря создать другой словарь?

Tags: python, словари

Есть список словарей вида:

```
lst = [
{'name': 'Bruce Willis', 'age': '65', 'height': '183'},
{'name': 'Charles Chaplin', 'age': '131', 'height': '163'},
{'name': 'Jennifer Lawrence', 'age': '30', 'height': '175'}
]
```

Нужно из такого словаря создать новый словарь такого вида:

```
{
'Bruce Willis' : {'age': '65', 'height': '183'},
'Charles Chaplin' : {'age': '131', 'height': '163'},
'Jennifer Lawrence' : {'age': '30', 'height': '175'}
}
```

Пытаюсь обойти словари таким кодом, но споткнулся с присвоением значения в виде другого словаря:

```
newDict = {}  
for elem in lst:
    if elem.get('name') not in newDict:
        newDict[elem.get('name')] = {}
    else:
        newDict[elem.get('name')] = {elem.get('age') = } ????
```

Вот тут запнулся, не могу понять, как добавить значения в виде словаря.
Помогите разобраться и подскажите (если можно, то без генераторов и лямбд).
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
newDict = {item.pop('name'): item for item in lst}
```

---

**Объяснение:**

Это так называемый *генератор словаря* — начинайте читать с конца, с `for item in lst`:

> «Для всякого элемента `item` в списке (словарей) `lst` включите `item.pop('name'): item` в этот (сейчас создаваемый) словарь.»

Метод `pop('name')` возвращает значение ключа `'name'`, устраняя его из словаря `item`.

Comment: Очень элегантно!

Comment: @nomnoms12, спасибо.

Comment: Спасибище! Нигде не встречал такого простого объяснения генератора.

Comment: @baston, не стоит. :-)

Answer (score 3):

***Пример:***

```py
li = [
    {'name': 'Bruce Willis', 'age': '65', 'height': '183'},
    {'name': 'Charles Chaplin', 'age': '131', 'height': '163'},
    {'name': 'Jennifer Lawrence', 'age': '30', 'height': '175'}
]

d = {}
for x in li:
    name = x['name']
    del x['name']

    d[name] = x
print(d)
```

***stdout:***

```py
{'Bruce Willis': {'age': '65', 'height': '183'}, 'Charles Chaplin': {'age': '131', 'height': '163'}, 'Jennifer Lawrence': {'age': '30', 'height': '175'}}
```